# Можно ли вернуться в старый коммит и произвести "безболезненно" изменения?

Tags: git

Есть одна миграция, которая была N коммитов назад. После того коммита, в котором находится эта миграция, было еще множество коммитов. Включая тот коммит, в которым была очистка миграций (удаление всех использованных миграций).

Сейчас обнаружил одну критическую ошибку в этой миграции.

Знаю что можно вернуться к коду того коммита, а затем ввести правки. Но я не знаю что сделать дальше, так как по сути эти изменения находятся в какой-то особой ветке, которой нет в репозитории. В целом, я просто не знаю, можно ли как-нибудь безопасно внести правки, что по итогу иметь коммит, (предполагаю) смерженный в тот самый проблемный коммит.

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить эту досадную ситуацию...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72248/discussion-on-question-by-colibri--------).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем кто писал выше. Каждый из вас действительно помог мне тем или иным советом.

Собрав всю вашу информацию воедино я поступил следующим образом.

Меня от проблемной миграции отделяло примерно 150 коммитов. Мною было решено пойти по самому простому на мой взгляд пути:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~200
```

В открывшемся списке коммитов я взял строку самого последнего коммита, в котором была переписанная миграция, и вставил после старого коммита (его строки) с проблемной миграцией. Также у строки нового коммита я заменил `pick` на `squash`, чтобы слить новый коммит с предыдущим (старым).

Дальше сохранил и закрыл.

Я использую Git Tower 2-ой версии, поэтому дальнейшие действия у меня свелись к простым "шаблонным" кликам. То есть дальше я тупо перепроходил коммит за коммитом и исправлял конфликты.

В итоге запушились все 140 с чем-то коммитов по новой. И моя проблема решилась.

*P.S. На мой взгляд это был простой способ (потому что я это делал первый раз), так как мне показалось, что я полностью буду контролировать процесс. Так оно и было.*

Comment: Ну, с первым rebase'ом!

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понимаю, требуется восстановить (частично) состояние репозитория до удаления миграций из проекта.
Навскидку, я вижу пару вариантов:

1. Найти коммит, в котором всё было в порядке, и сделать от него новый бранч. Затем внести в нём все необходимые правки и вмержить его в основной бранч, решая по ходу мержа конфликт (один бранч апдейтит миграции, другой удаляет).
2. Найти коммит, удаляющий миграции из проекта, и применить к нему Revert commit — в результате будет создан новый коммит, "отменяющий" действие того. Фактически, это будет новый независимый коммит, который добавит удалённые миграции обратно в проект.